# `source` command works in one Makefile/make target but not another in same script

Tags: cmake, makefile

The following entry in my `Makefile` works fine:

```
# in Makefile
format:
    source .venv/bin/activate && isort src/hercl/
    source .venv/bin/activate && black src/hercl/ -l 120
    source .venv/bin/activate && flake8 src/hercl/ --max-line-length 120 --ignore=W605
```

```
$ make format
..
All done! ✨  ✨
4 files reformatted, 20 files left unchanged.
```

But this one does not :

```
# in Makefile
activate_venv:
    source .venv/bin/activate
```

```
$make activate_venv
source .venv/bin/activate
make: source: No such file or directory
make: *** [activate_venv] Error 1
```

Why will the same command `source <something>` work in one target and not the other?

Comment: Invisible characters? Did you try `cat -A Makefile`?

Comment: `source` is a bash built-in. Probably, in the second case your Makefile uses shell other than bash. Try to create [mcve]. Also, the line `source .venv/bin/activate` seems useless in Makefile: because separate Makefile's lines uses separate shell environments, sourcing something in one environment, corresponding to one line in Makefile, won't affect the other environment, corresponding to the other line.

Comment: @Tsyvarev agreed about the second comment: I have changed to `source .venv/bin/activate && 'command'`